# How to add class to nested Dom element using VANILLA JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This is my simple code, and I want that when the user clicks on the first cell it will become to blue background (only the clicked cell).
I think the only problem I don't know how to select/refer to a specific cell because it's a nested element.

** If you can do it with "by tag name" it would be nice.

Thanks for your help!

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Aviliable</td>
            <td>Aviliable</td>
            <td>Aviliable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
td {
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

JS:

```
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].document.getElementByTagName("td")[0];

td.onclick = function () {
  td += "blue";
}
```

Comment: And this should affect *only* the first cell, or any cell that the user clicks? What happens if the user clicks the same cell twice? Or thrice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting elements by tag name works fine. you first get the first row from the document (hence you use document.getElementsByTagName()) Now that you have the first row, from there you just need to use getElementsByTagName (you don't want to search the document, just the row you already got).

```js
var td = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]


td.onclick = function () {
  td.classList.add("blue");
}
```

```css
td {
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Aviliable</td>
            <td>Aviliable</td>
            <td>Aviliable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
                <td>Aviliable</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
   <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target` to pick the cell which you want to add style to,

```js
var firstTableRow = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
firstTableRow.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.classList.add('blue');
})
```

[Fiidle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/uzumaki_naruto/vtqfbwry/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you

```js
function changeColor(cell){
   var elems = document.querySelectorAll("th");

   [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
    // alert("hello");

       el.classList.remove("blue");
   });
   cell.classList.add("blue");
 }
```

```css
.blue{
background-color:blue
}
```

```html
<table border="1px" width="100%">
  <tr>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th  onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
   <th onclick="changeColor(this)">1</th>
  </tr>
 </table>
```